# Tabela dinâmica

Tags: javascript, html

Amigos,
Preciso criar uma tabela dinâmica em HTML e JavaScript que funcionará da seguinte forma:

Tenho uma série de itens em um ComboBox e ao selecionar, cria uma coluna em uma tabela.
Após, adiciono outra ComboBox, onde seleciono outro item e após este item cria uma outra coluna na Tabela.

Em anexo segue exemplo.

Por favor, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Muito obrigado[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem algum código de tentativas suas pra mostrar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode apdatar esse código para seu uso:

```
<select class="input-xxlarge empresaRegistro" name="empresaRegistro" id="empresaRegistro" style="width: 715px !important;" onChange="getFuncionario()">
    <option value="">Selecione a Empresa</option>
    <?
        foreach($lista_cedente as $valor){
    ?>
        <option value="<? echo $valor->idCedente; ?>"><? echo $valor->razaosocial; ?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```

Script jQuery:

```
<script>
        function getFuncionario() {
            var id = $('#empresaRegistro').val();
            $(".idFuncionarioLista").append('<option value="0">Carregando...</option>');
            $.post("<? echo base_url(''); ?>proventos/ajax/funcionario/"+id,
                {idFuncionarioLista:jQuery(id).val()},
                function(valor){
                     $(".idFuncionarioLista").html(valor);
                }
            );
        }

</script>
```

Neste esquema: Quando seleciona a Empresa de Registro (campo empresaRegistro), entro pelo ajax e busco todos os dados e listo eles embaixo num próximo campo select também chamado idFuncionarioLista. Podes fazer o mesmo tipo de jquery para buscar o próximo select, usando então onchange="NOMEDAFUNCAO()" no select idFuncionarioLista por exemplo.